# Elemento sem propriedades

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Veja o seguinte trecho de código abaixo:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('myDiv');

console.log('element: ', element);

console.log('has tagName property: ', element.hasOwnProperty('tagName'));
console.log('all properties: ', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(element));

console.log('tagName value: ', element.tagName);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Perceba que o elemento existe, mas todas as tentativas de verificar a existência das propriedades do mesmo são sem sucesso. Mas no final consigo obter normalmente o valor da propriedade que, segundo as verificações, não deveria existir.

Segundo a documentação do [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) a função `hasOwnProperty()` só retorna propriedades diretas do objeto avaliado. Nesse caso a propriedade `tagName` não deveria ser retornado?

Comment: Então, a propriedade `tagName` é herdada de `Object`, então não é uma propriedade direta do elemento em questão.

Comment: Como dito pelo Anderson, a propriedade não se encontra no objeto e sim no objeto parente. Desta forma você irá listar as propriedades: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(element.__proto__.__proto__)`

Comment: Bem, muito obrigado pelos comentários! Talvez uma resposta que contemple um pouco da hierarquia básica dos objetos em javascript para este caso em específico (um elemento html) seja suficiente para finalizar essa pergunta.